# $V_k$ being a model of ZFC whenever $k$ is strongly inaccessible

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

> ZFC implies that the $V_k$ is a model of ZFC whenever $k$ is strongly
>   inaccessible..

So if $k$ is weakly inaccessible, it can't be a model of ZFC? Why is it like this?

> And ZF implies that the Godel universe $L_k$ is a model of ZFC
>   whenever $k$ is weakly inaccessible.

Again, the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing we should note that $L$ satisfies GCH, so if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible it is strongly inaccessible in $L$. This will be important later.

Now, to see that $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC if $\kappa$ is inaccessible we need to note several things:

1. If $x\in  V_\kappa$ then $|x|<\kappa$, this is because $\kappa$ is inaccessible so $\lambda<\kappa\implies 2^\lambda<\kappa$, and so we can prove that for all $\alpha<\kappa$, $|V_\alpha|<\kappa$ (this is by transfinite induction).
2. Extensionality holds immediately, so does regularity and infinity axioms. The power set holds in $V_\alpha$ for any limit ordinal, so it holds here as well. In fact all but union and replacement axioms hold.
3. Union holds because if $A\in V_\kappa$ we have that $|A|<\kappa$, and if $A\in V_\kappa$ then all the members of $A$ are in $V_\kappa$, so their cardinality is $<\kappa$. Since $\kappa$ is regular we have that whenever we take a union of less than $\kappa$ sets of size less than $\kappa$ the result has cardinality less than $\kappa$. It remains to verify that the union is indeed a set in $V_\kappa$, but we can do this by seeing that the rank of the union is the supremum ($+1$ maybe) of the ranks of the members of the members of $A$. All those ordinals are below $\kappa$, so unions are below $\kappa$ and we are fine.
4. Replacement holds for the same reason. You need to show that whenever $f$ is a definable function in $V_\kappa$ (perhaps with parameters from there) and $A\in V_\kappa$ then $f''A\in V_\kappa$.
5. Choice is obvious by all the above. Every set in $V_\kappa$ is in bijection with an ordinal below $\kappa$.

Now going back to $L$, show that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible then $L_\kappa=V_\kappa$. Since weakly inaccessible in $L$ is the same as inaccessible we are done.

Comment: Could you please recommend some books, where I can read about axiomatic ZFC, models and inaccessible cardinals?

Comment: You can find concentrated information in my note, The Five WH's of Set Theory. http://karagila.org/2016/the-five-whs-of-set-theory/

Comment: Sorry, this did not helped much. Could you recommend some specific book about ZFC and these $V_k$ models?

Comment: Your question tells me that you *should* learn set theory from one of the books I've listed in the note. If you're comfortable with the basic notions of elementary set theory (up to ordinals), you can easily pick one of many books mentioned in the list of advanced books. If not, then try reading one of the books in the list of elementary set theory first.